# ion_auth adds unnecessary index.php in HTTP location

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis-7, ion-auth

Recently setup ion_auth in my CI project. Everything is working well for the most part. However, when the user logs out of the web site, they are redirected to

> http://*website*/index.php/auth/login

instead of the expected

> http://*website*/auth/login

location. This causes an issue upon signing in as the location given after login is

> http://*website*/index.php/*website*

which is an invalid location.

The server is IIS7 and not Apache. Using the configuration below in the web.config at the root of the site:

```
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="index.php" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument> 
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="base64_encode.*\(.*\)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(\&lt;|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E)" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="_REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" url="index.php" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2">
                <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/index.php" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(/component/)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you removed the string `index.php` from this config item (in application/config/config.php)?

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

should be

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Redirects and uri generation are based upon this value.

Comment: This corrects the issue during logout so that it directs to http://website.com/auth/login. However, at login time it still redirects to http://website.com/website.com. I had thought that I would need to leave that variable in place but after reading the suggestion to remove it that makes sense. My config['base_url'] is set to '/website.com'.

Comment: Removed the $config['base_url'] as well and it works fine. However, concerned that having no base_url defined will bite me later. I could just be paranoid.

Comment: `$config['base_url']` should be an absolute url with trailing slash, such as `http://website.com/` and not simply `website.com` which would explain why you're getting redirected to website.com/website.com (it's like doing `<a href="website.com">link</a>` )